# :target css selector not working in polymer

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I'm using Polymer and I noticed that the `:target` css selector doesn't work.

For example

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <style>
            :target {
                border: 2px solid red;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="test">This is a :target test</div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>

<a href="#test">Click me</a>
<my-element></my-element>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sqo159z/5/)

Any suggestions how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit: I'm not very familar with shadow DOM and absolutely not familar with Polymer but I'd like to tell you my view on this because your intention looks somewhat strange to me and *this* is too long for a comment.

#### Short

You can't use the pseudo selector `:target` within a shadow host.

---

#### Long

Unfortunately I was not able to find *clear* evidences in these resources

- http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/
- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/

but some hints...

The goal of Web Components was to give us the ability to build individual and isolated components that can be used in a document without caring of their inner function or style.

If a component could directly reach the "outside" document or if the outside document could reach any shadow hosts element directly, this would completely break the intention of Web Components.

Imagine what would happen if you insert two instances of your `<my-element>`. Both contain the same ID, which one should be targeted?

Of course it's possible to reach the shadow document, or the containing document from within the shadow document, but only through `::shadow` or `:host` respectively.

To me its logical that the browser can't select elements using a mere `:target` selector since the target is the matter of the document (it's URL is targeted to some ID) not of any shadow DOM. It's also not possible to reach a shadow tree node with `document.getElementById()` from within the *container document*.

The [CSS scoping spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/) which also adresses the Shadow DOM concepts states:

> Why is the shadow host so weird?
>
> **The shadow host lives outside the shadow tree, and its markup is in
>   control of the page author, not the component author.**
>
> It would not be very good if a component used a particular class name
>   internally in a shadow tree, and the page author using the component
>   accidentally also used the the same class name and put it on the host
>   element. Such a situation would result in accidental styling that is
>   impossible for the component author to predict, and confusing for the
>   page author to debug.

([3.1.1. Host Elements in a Shadow Tree](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#host-element-in-tree))

I'd say this is another evidence: the shadow host (viewed from outside) itself will keep the active (focus) state while handling the focus inside its tree.

> To maintain encapsulation, the value of the Document object's focus
>   API property activeElement must be adjusted. To prevent loss of
>   information when adjusting this value, each shadow root must also have
>   an activeElement property to store the value of the focused element in
>   the shadow tree.

([6.3 Active Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#h3_active-element))

---

#### One possible solution to your problem

If your intention was to highlight only the `div`, when your shadow element is `:target`ed this might be the correct style within your shadow document:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" constructor="" attributes="">
  <template>
     <style>
         :host(:target) #inner {
             color: #0c0;
         }
     </style>
     <content>Hello World!</content>
     <div id="inner">This is a :target test</div>
...
```

It will highlight the `<div>` with green text, when your shadow element `<my-element id="outer"></my-element>` is targeted by `#outer`.

If this was not your intention and you really wanted to be able to target `#inner` from outside, **I'd say this is not possible** (see the "longer" part ;).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to link to elements inside shadow dom, because you may have multiple instances of the outer element in same page so you'll get multiple elements with same id.

However when you request a url with `#elementId` the browser will only look in light dom for the according element.

If you still need to style shadow dom elements you could simulate `:target` selector:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" constructor="" attributes="">
  <template>
    <style>
      #inner[target] {
        border: 2px solid red;
      }
    </style>
    <content>Hello World!</content>
    <div id="inner" target?="{{innerTargetted}}">This is a :target test</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
      ready: function() {
        $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
          this.innerTargetted = window.location.hash == '#inner';
        }.bind(this));
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/raMKRx).